# Best practice spread pod across the node evenly

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have 4 node with different zone:

```
Node A : zone a
Node B : zone b
Node C : zone c
Node D : zone c
```

I want to spread the pod to Node A, B and C. I have Deployment that have 3 replicas to spread across those node, each pod each node. My deployments using kustomization and ArgoCD to deploy. Using the topologySpreadConstraint need to be update the label but labels are immutable on this case.

Current deployment condition using this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-apps
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - my-apps
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
          whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: my-apps
              version: v1
...
```

I've done add label for those 3 nodes and this configuration **works well at first time**. But when it comes to update the deployment and rolling update, The pods on nodes going to imbalance.

```
zone a : 2 pod
zone b : 1 pod
zone c : 0 pod
```

I've done playing with podAntiAffinity but its return as pending if I use hard affinity and still imbalance if I use soft affinity. Any suggestion best practice for this case? did I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rolling updates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/) cause some pods to be removed from nodes and others to be added. This can cause the pods on nodes to become imbalanced, as the pods that were already on the nodes will remain, but the pods that are added during the update will likely be different. To prevent this from happening, it is important to use the [maxUnavailable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable) option in the rolling update strategy. This allows you to specify the maximum number of pods that can be removed from a node during the rolling update, ensuring that the pods on each node remain balanced.

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml --strategy=RollingUpdate  --strategy-rolling-update-maxUnavailable=1
```

This command will create or update a deployment with the rolling update strategy, and the maxUnavailable option set to 1.This will ensure that no more than 1 pod is removed from a node during the rolling update, thus keeping the pods across nodes balanced.Try it and let me know if this works

If you are scaling down the pods, as per [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#known-limitations) limitations:

There's no guarantee that the constraints remain satisfied when Pods are removed. For example, scaling down a Deployment may result in an imbalanced Pods distribution.You can use a tool such as the [Descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler) to rebalance the Pods distribution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, its works well. Is it possible doing this without downtime if we directly on connecting to the one of node ip and port?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do a rolling upgrade without downtime by directly connecting to one of the node IPs and ports.This can be done by connecting directly to each node's IP and port, or by using a load balancer to help distribute traffic between the nodes and prevent any single node from becoming overloaded. Additionally, it is important to the Descheduler to rebalance the pods distribution if scaling down the pods, as there is no guarantee that the constraints remain satisfied when pods are removed.